# How to load part of JSON file to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file that has contents like this:

```
a {"field1":{"field2":"val","field3":"val"...}}
b {"field1":{"field2":"val","field3":"val"...}}
...
```

and I was able to load the file to a table like this:

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════
║ ID ║  JSON                                         ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════
║  a ║ {"field1":{"field2":"val","field3":"val"...}} ║
║  b ║ {"field1":{"field2":"val","field3":"val"...}} ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

How can I make it into something like this?

```
╔════╦═════════════════════════════════════
║ ID ║ field2  ║field3 ║...     ║...     ║
╠════╬═════════════════════════════════════
║  a ║ val     ║val    ║..      ║...     ║
║  b ║ val     ║val    ║..      ║...     ║
╚════╩═════════════════════════════════════
```

Since it is a partial json file, I cannot do `read.json`
I saw this post too  [convert lines of json in RDD to dataframe in apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818368/convert-lines-of-json-in-rdd-to-dataframe-in-apache-spark)
But my json string is a nested json and it is very long, so I do not want to list out all the fields.
I also tried

```
#solr_data is the data frame made from the file, and json is the column with the json string, session is a SparkSession
json_table = solr_data.select(solr_data["json"]).rdd.map(lambda x:session.read.json(x))
```

That did not work well. I can't `show()` nor `collect()` for that, `createDataFrame()` didn't work for that either.

Comment: how does the exact content look like? Mind posting a sample? what is `a long string` and how are they related to `val`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select("JSON.field1.*")` to "destructure" sub-JSON to columns.